# Convert an existing customised Debian 10 Installation to Live ISO

Tags: live-usb, iso, livecd, portability, mx-linux

Can someone help please?

I already did some research and found:

1. Linux [Respin](http://www.linuxrespin.org) completely messed up my system when trying to install dependencies (removed a lot of packages I needed) - at least I am using a VM so I could revert to a snapshot
2. Trying [Linux Live Kit](https://www.linux-live.org/) I am building a tentative ISO while writing this post - will keep you updated even though I am not confident it will work as I wish

I also read about [MX Linux](https://mx-linux.org) which has a tool called [MX Snapshot](https://mxlinux.org/wiki/help-files/help-mx-save-system-to-iso-snapshot/). Can that utility be used on Debian?

I would appreciate if anyone has further ideas and recommendations since I really want to get this thing done the proper way... I used to use [SystemBack](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-systemback-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-18-10) way back but now it is not being maintained anymore I guess...

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY - will have to change the base of my distro to Ubuntu then I guess...